# Word: insert an Autotext shape, then move it

Tags: vba, ms-word

I'm trying to insert an autotext item into a header, and then move the autotext item only if it is on an even page that's also the first page in a section.

My code will insert the autotext, but I can't figure out how to move it.

```
Sub InsertHeader()
Dim oShape As Shape
Dim PageNumber As Integer
Dim oSection As Section
Dim oHeader As HeaderFooter
For Each oSection In ActiveDocument.Sections
    If oSection.Index > 1 Then

    For Each oHeader In oSection.Headers
        oHeader.Range.Select
        PageNumber = Selection.Information(wdActiveEndPageNumber)
        If oHeader.Exists Then
            Select Case oHeader.Index
            Case Is = wdHeaderFooterFirstPage
                If PageNumber Mod 2 = 0 Then
                    ActiveDocument.AttachedTemplate.AutoTextEntries("HeaderFirst"). _
Insert Where:=Selection.Range

                End If
            End Select
        End If
    Next oHeader
    End If
Next oSection
End Sub
```

I tried putting `Insert Where:=Selection.Range Left:=CentimetersToPoints(2.26)` but the VBA editor won't accept that. I also tried finding all shapes in the header and moving them:

```
                ActiveDocument.AttachedTemplate.AutoTextEntries("HeaderFirst"). _
    Insert Where:=Selection.Range
                    For Each oShape In oHeader.Shapes
                        oShape.Left = CentimetersToPoints(2.26)
                        ''oHeader.Range.Shape(1).Left = CentimetersToPoints(1)
                    Next oShape
```

But that moves the shapes in every header in the document, not just the shape I inserted.

Comment: I wonder if you could just set up the document with different odd and even headers - definitely do-able - and different first pages per section? I see you can do different first pages per document, and it looks like maybe per section. See the Layout tab of the Page Setup dialog.

Comment: Word can do different odd and even headers, plus one first page per section. Basically Word assumes that the first page per section is always on an odd page. I need two 'first page' options for each section, due to customer requirements to have a section start on an even page.

Comment: your try will always behave in this way. first-odd-even pages per section are as they are- you can't change that rules. what you add/change/move in odd header will be visible in all odd headers within this section. What I could suggest- add that text to `Document.Content` in appropriate page and position or...add additional section breaks. If you find programmatic way of breaking the rules please, show it here. Finally, try to convince your customer to change the rules.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found it!
After inserting the header, I have to select it, then move the selection:

```
oHeader.Range.Select
Selection.Range.ShapeRange.Left = CentimetersToPoints(2.26)
```

Also, I needed to make sure the header existed before inserting anything. I solved that by having the program that generates the Word file (Author-it) insert a temporary header.